# Unable to archive updated iOS PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, archive

I recently upgraded my PhoneGap app from 2.4.0 to 3.4.0. To do this I had to create a new project using NodeJS, then copy all the www files and resources into the new project. I added a new ios platform. It compiles and runs in xcode 5.1. The simulator works too.

Now I want to submit this to the app store as an update to my previous version. The problem is the "Product > Archive" menu in xcode is disabled.

Has anybody who can give me some direction been through this process? Or direct me to where I can get some help?

======

UPDATE: I found that I the target device must be set to iOS Device in order to archive a project. Now Archive is enabled. I run archive, but no archive is listed in the Organizer.

Still looking for help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you connect your device first. You cannot archive your project without a device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a simple oddity with Xcode. If you have a simulator selected you cannot archive. Choose iOS Device and then you can archive, with or without an actual physical device connected.